# How to continue for-loop if the query doesn't exist on the website

Tags: for-loop, web, screen-scraping

I'm scraping news websites to see if there are articles that corespond with the words in a list. I get an error when the word from the list doesn't exist on the news website. What code do I need to add in order to continue every time a word doesn't exist?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
import time

# load list json file 
with open("words.json") as json_file:
    data_words = json.load(json_file)

for item in data_words:
    query = item 
    print(query)
    
    # start timing 
    start_time = time.time()
    
    # scrape newswebsite 
    base_url = "https://www.pbs.org/newshour/search-results?q=%22"+ query +"%22&pnb="
    
    # scrape DutchNews
    #base_url = "https://www.dutchnews.nl/page/"+ number +"/?s="+ query
    
    # there are 50 pages to interate
    # get the page 
    url = base_url + "1"
    page = requests.get(url)

    # convert to soup, is main object
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
    
    # grab number of paginations
    pagination_links = soup.find(class_="pagination__numbers")

    links = pagination_links.findAll("a")
    
    # get last item of list, know the lenght and grab last item 
    last_item = len(links) - 1
    
    total_pages = int(links[last_item].get_text())
    
    # put data out of forloops
    data = []
    
    # cast i to string
    for i in range(1, total_pages + 1):
        url = base_url + str(i)
        print("Retrieving", url)
        
    # make sure page and soup are in for loop
    # get page
        page = requests.get(url)
    
    # convert to soup object
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
    
    # get all the search result titles, add All
        results_list = soup.findAll(class_="search-result__text")
    
    # timesleep
        time.sleep(2)
        
    # search in list
        for item in results_list:
            title = item.find("h4").get_text()
    # timesleep
            time.sleep(2)
            datetime = item.find("span").get_text()
            snippet = item.find("p").get_text().strip()
            url = item.find("a")["href"]
    # create dictionairy
            article = {
                "query": query,
                "title": title,
                "datetime": datetime,
                "snippet": snippet,
                "url": url
            }
    # has to be in line with article
            data.append(article)
        
# strip white spaces use, strip() after get_text()
print(data)

# print timing
print(time.time() - start_time, 's')

# save this with json
with open("pbs_words_results.json", "w") as outfile:
    json.dump(data, outfile)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `AttributeError` basically indicates that `pagination_links` is `None`. Since you declare it as `pagination_links = soup.find(class_="pagination__numbers")` it means that there is not an element with class `pagination__numbers`.
In this case all you would have to do is check whether it is `None`, and if so just continue with the next item of the loop:

```py
for item in data_words:
    query = item 
    print(query)
    
    # start timing 
    start_time = time.time()
    
    # scrape newswebsite 
    base_url = "https://www.pbs.org/newshour/search-results?q=%22"+ query +"%22&pnb="
    
    # scrape DutchNews
    #base_url = "https://www.dutchnews.nl/page/"+ number +"/?s="+ query
    
    # there are 50 pages to interate
    # get the page 
    url = base_url + "1"
    page = requests.get(url)

    # convert to soup, is main object
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
    
    # grab number of paginations
    pagination_links = soup.find(class_="pagination__numbers")
    # check if pagination_links is None
    if not pagination_links:
        continue

    ....
```

You should also do this check with other variables, so that you don't encounter an error again.